# list is not loading in swiftUI after. update

Tags: ios, swiftui

I getting some data from server using AlamoFire, the request is fine the models all good, the problem is, after the request completes, my @State variable does not updates.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ViewLaundryHome: View {

    @State var items = LaundryItemCategoryViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(items.items.count.description) // returns 0 and never updates
        }
    }
}

class LaundryItemCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<LaundryItemCategoryViewModel, Never>()

    var items = [LaundryItemCategory.Result.Doc]() { didSet { didChange.send(self) } }

    init() {
        productCategoryR {
            let d = try! JSONDecoder().decode(LaundryItemCategory.self, from: $0)
            self.items = (d.result?.docs!)!
            print(self.items.count) // returns 5
        }
    }
}
```

I think I did exactly as this video on youtube, but it does not work for me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT4wGOc2jd4&t=17s

Here's my data model:

```
struct LaundryItemCategory: Codable {
    let result: Result?
    let id: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case result = "Result"
        case id = "Id"
    }

    struct Result: Codable {
        let docs: [Doc]?
        let currentPage: Int?
        let pages: Int?
        let limit: Int?
        let total: Int?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case docs = "Docs"
            case currentPage = "CurrentPage"
            case pages = "Pages"
            case limit = "Limit"
            case total = "Total"
        }

        struct Doc: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
            let id: Int
            let title: String
            let media: String
            let price: Int

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id = "Id"
                case title = "Title"
                case media = "Media"
                case price = "Price"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After. some digging:

something weird happened. I added another state to the app, and changed it using a textfield, at the exact moment that I change the value of the new State, the first state updates :-/

```
@State var items = LaundryItemCategoryViewModel()

@State var i = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(items.items.count.description)
        TextField("sss", text: $i)
        Text(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said, you need to make items in ViewLaundryHome as an ObservedObject in order to receive updates. In LaundryItemCategoryViewModel, you need to publish the items. Here's the working code tested in iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.3 and Xcode version 11.3.1. Let me know if this works.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ViewLaundryHome: View {
    @ObservedObject var items = LaundryItemCategoryViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(items.items.count.description)
        }
    }
}

class LaundryItemCategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // var didChange = PassthroughSubject<LaundryItemCategoryViewModel, Never>() // Not needed

    @Published var items = [LaundryItemCategory.Result.Doc]() // Add Published
    // { didSet { didChange.send(self) } } - Not needed

    init() {
        // Delaying the creation of data to mimic data coming from a webserver
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5.0) {
            let x = LaundryItemCategory.Result.Doc(id: 1, title: "Test", media: "Test", price: 0)
            let y = LaundryItemCategory.Result.Doc(id: 2, title: "Test", media: "Test", price: 0)

            self.items.append(x)
            self.items.append(y)
        }

        print(self.items.count) // returns 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some limited working code, so I can debug?

Comment: PassthroughSubject<LaundryItemCategoryViewModel, Never>()  -- Is this line not required?

Comment: That's not needed.